# How to deploy webapp from local machine to a remote server ( play framework 1.2.7 + nginx + jetty + debian )

Tags: deployment, nginx, jetty, playframework-1.x

I can't find tutorial about remote deploy to a remote server

for play 1.2.7 + nginx + jetty + debian.

Follows my vps configure for nginx + jetty + debian .

http://wiki.nginx.org/JavaServers

My local machine use play 1.2.7.

Nginx deny war file and i dont`t know how to deploy webapp of play to a remote server.

Please hint me or where is it about remote deploy. THX

Comment: I can't understand in docs for Play 2.x and in the doc. For example,         in local machine , can i key in " play start my webapp" ,

Comment: For example,         in local machine , command line key in " play start mywebapp " , then remote server begin deploy until successful. Can i do this thing?

Answer (score 0):

Just use nginx as a reverse proxy for you app working as described [in the doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/production).

Sample config for nginx you'll find [in docs for Play 2.x](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/HTTPServer)